# Meaning .long function_name in Assembly Language

Tags: c, assembly, x86, disassembly

Suppose i have two functions in x86 assembly language defined as :

```
.globl func_name1;      
.type func_name1, @function;
.align 2;
 func_name1:
 //Some assembly instructions here.
```

and similarly second function:

```
.globl func_name2;      
.type func_name2, @function;
.align 2;
 func_name2:
 //Some assembly instructions here.
```

Now what is the meaning of the following-

```
.data
.globl var_temp
 var_temp:
   .long func_name1
   .long func_name2
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It looks like a jump table to me, i.e. an array of pointers to functions.

Comment: @PaulR So u mean var_temp[0] contains memory address of func_name1 and var_temp[1] contains memory address of func_name2? If yes, how ?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it - it's just like an array of function pointers in C.

Comment: `.long` tells the assembler "reserve a 4-byte chunk of memory". The following function name tells it "and initialize with the address of this label" - function names are labels in assembly. As a result, at `var_temp` you have an array of two 4-byte function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those .long's define pointers to functions. `var_temp` looks like an array of 2 pointers to functions.